# Algorítimo de paredes do Habbo

Tags: javascript, jogos, game

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo em JavaScript e o ambiente dele é muito parecido com o do Habbo: Um piso e paredes somente no fundo do piso.

[image: Quarto no Habbo]

O mapa do jogo é dinâmico e representado por uma matriz de números onde 0 indica que não haverá piso e os demais se referem a altura do piso.

Percebi que as paredes são renderizadas começando pelo canto inferior esquerdo e terminando no canto superior direito.

Tenho este código até então, o problema dele é que em alguns casos não é renderizado o bloco, como o bloco (2,2) que deveria ser um bloco vertical ou horizontal.

```js
const $floor = document.getElementById("floor");
const $wall = document.getElementById("wall");

const WH = "-"; // Parede Horizontal
const WV = "|"; // Parede Vertical
const WC = "+"; // Parece Canto
const WN = "."; // Piso (Sem parede)

// Mapa de piso
const floor = [
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];

// Mapa de paredes
const walls = new Array(floor.length)
  .fill(null)
  .map((_, y) =>
    new Array(floor[0].length)
      .fill(null)
      .map((_, x) => (floor[y][x] === 0 ? " " : WN))
  );

const floorRows = floor.length;
const floorCols = floor[0].length;

let maxVX = Infinity;

// Paredes Horizontais
wallsH: for (let y = 0; y < floorRows; y++) {
  const row = floor[y];

  // Percorre às colunas até o primeiro bloco vertical
  for (let x = 0; x <= floorCols; x++) {
    // Se for 0, não inserir paredes
    if (!row[x]) continue;

    // Não enfileirar paredes horizontais verticalmente
    for (let wy = y; wy >= 0; wy--) {
      const block = walls[wy][x];
      if (block === WH || block === WC) continue wallsH;
    }

    // Renderiza
    walls[y][x] = WH;
  }
}

// Paredes Verticais
for (let y = 0; y < floorRows; y++) {
  const row = floor[y];

  for (let x = 0; x < floorCols; x++) {
    // Não testar blocos com 0
    if (!row[x]) continue;

    // Não enfileirar paredes verticais
    // horizontalmente
    if (x > maxVX) break;

    // Define a posição X máxima para o bloco atual
    maxVX = x;

    // Bloco com canto se já existir
    // um bloco horizontal nesta posição
    let conner = walls[y][x] === WH;

    // Renderiza
    walls[y][x] = conner ? WC : WV;
  }
}

$floor.textContent = floor.map(r => r.join(" ")).join("\n");
$wall.textContent = walls.map(r => r.join(" ")).join("\n");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <pre id="floor"></pre>
  <pre id="wall"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Mais, mais..., qual é a dúvida afinal?

Comment: Preciso criar este algorítimo, não sei por onde começar

Comment: É aí, fica fora do escopo... Sugiro dar uma estudada antes e ter uma base do que pretende fazer, e  quando aparecer dúvidas específicas você posta, ok...

Comment: Mas o que vou estudar?
preciso converter uma matriz em outra que represente somente as paredes

Comment: Você pode entrar no chat, e falar com o pessoal mais informalmente, para ver se alguém tem alguma ideia que possa te dar uma luz, para seu começo, boa sorte...

Comment: Estudar que eu digo é no sentido, de ter as informações necessárias para organizar as etapas de um algorítimo que atinja seu objetivo... Provavelmente se eu usar de metodologia socrática, para alinhar suas ideias, descobriremos que certamente elas já estão aí... Então, organize as informações que já tem em um algorítimo e se surgir alguma duvida, você edita sua questão, que com certeza aparecerá ajuda. Entende, o que quero dizer?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Só pra constar, estou quase certo que este sistema é chamado de "isométrico", se procurar por algo assim vai encontrar exemplos: ["create simple isometric game javascript"](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+simple+isometric+game+javascript)

Comment: Sim o mapa é isométrico, mas não achei nada parecido nas pesquisas que fiz

Comment: Logo na primeira busca achei: https://github.com/nick-aschenbach/simple-isometric-tile-engine, não testei mas cabe a vc experimentar é claro, e estudar o código .... e achei isto também http://jsiso.com/tutorials.html, o que me parece otimo para o seu caso

Comment: A engine de renderização eu tenho, o que preciso é um algorítimo pra saber quais os locais onde serão renderizadas as paredes